# JAVA, array taking a variable number of objects as parameters

Tags: java, arrays, object, variadic-functions

I am trying to get an array to take a variable number of objects as input. I am new to programming so I apologize in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public class Rating{
    double [] Ratings;
    int CustomerID;
    int Domain;

    public Rating (int id, int d, double [] x) {
        double [] Ratings = x;
        int CustomerID=id;
        int Domain=d;
    }
}

public class All_user{
    double [] All_users;

    public All_user(Rating...argument) {
        double [] All_users={Rating...argument};
    }
}
```

However, I am get this error associated with double[] All_users={Rating..arguments);:

```
    Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "...", . expected
 - arguments cannot be resolved or is 
  not a field
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Variable names should be camelCase: Ratings -> ratings, CustomerID -> customerID (some prefer customerId) and you shouldnt use that underscore in the class name: All_users -> AllUsers. Try to get used to that, it makes your life easier. As a quick note: If the argument is defined as Rating... ratings (varargs), the param ratings is type of Ratings[].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes in your `All_user` class constructor; you're trying to set... something... of type `Ratings[]` to a class member of type `double[]`

You could do one of the following :

1- Have your `All_user`'s constructor receive an array (or variable-length arguments) be instances of `Rating` and simply assign it to the class member (an array) of the same type :

```
public class All_user{
    Rating [] All_users;

    public All_user(Rating...argument) {
        All_users = argument;  // arguments is a Rating[]
    }
}
```

or collect all values (`double Ratings`) from each `Rating` and map them into an array

```
public class All_user{
    double [] All_users;

    public All_user(Rating...argument) {
        ArrayList<Double> ratings = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (Rating r : argument) {
            for (double d : r.Ratings) ratings.add(d);
        }
        All_users = new double[ratings.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<ratings.size(); i++) All_users[i] = ratings.get(i);
    }
}
```

I think the latter is what you are trying to do. Also, note that your `Rating` class could also be rewritten as

```
public class Rating{
    double [] Ratings;
    int CustomerID;
    int Domain;

    public Rating (int id, int d, double...x) {
        double [] Ratings = x;
        int CustomerID=id;
        int Domain=d;
    }
}
```

FYI: The variable-length argument is always the last one in the declared arguments. More on varargs [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java).

Comment: Primitives such as double can not be a generic type arg in Java.

Comment: dang! didn't do Java for a while... it's not as pretty as it could be, but I fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length args (var-args) are accessed like an array. Assuming you want to flat-pack all ratings of all users into a single `double[]` in `All_user`, then:

```
public class All_user{
    double [] All_users;
    public All_user(Rating... argument) {
        int totalSize = 0;
        for(Rating r:argument)
            totalSize+=r.getRatings().length; //double[] Ratings
        double [] All_users= new double[totalSize];
        int index = 0;
        for(Rating r:argument){
            for(double r:r.getRatings()){
                 All_users[index] = r;
                 index++;
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`argument` is represented as an array of `Rating` objects, used in this context. Be really careful of using varargs though. It's rarely a good design decision unless you're making a library.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the **vargs** notation, the arg is handled as an array.  In your case, it would be an array of `Rating`. You can reference it within the method body as you would an array, ie as if it was declared as `arguments[]`.

A couple critiques:

1. You will not be able to cast your `Rating` to a `double`, so you are already running into trouble.
2. With regard to your error, the first thing to note is that the `...` notation is only used in the declaration of the method, not to refer to the arg within the method body.
3. It also looks as though you are referring to your arg as `arguments`, when you declare it as `argument`.
4. Further, you should add a space between your varg declaration `Rating...` and the name of the arg.