# Why was foo(Object... obj) implemented in Java1.5?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

As the two functions

```
foo(Object... obj)
{
for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
System.out.println(obj[i]);
}
```

and

```
foo(Object [] obj)
{
for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    System.out.println(obj[i]);
}
```

and the function call can be done

foo(obj,str,1);

foo({obj,str,1});

respectively , perform the same function and the latter existed from the very starting of java then why the Object... obj was implemented

Which one is better and why?

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/766559/130224

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `...` functions are a kind of [*syntactic sugar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) - they offer more convenient syntax (no braces) without alter anything else, including performance. The compiler does the same thing behind the scene, letting you use more convenient syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work:

```
foo({obj, str, 1});
```

You would need to do:

```
foo(new Object[] {obj, str, 1});
```

That's awkward enough that I'm very grateful for the varargs syntax. Functionally, you are correct that they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Plus one for Syntactic Sugar... So simply it just means it's there to make your code nicer. Here is an example:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        String str = "test";
        varArgsFoo(obj, str, 1); //Don't have to use an Array...
        varArgsFoo(new Object[]{obj, str, 1}); //But you can if it suits you.
        arrayFoo(new Object[]{obj, str, 1}); // Compiles, but you MUST pass in an Array.
        arrayFoo(obj, str, 1); // Won't compile!!! Varargs won't work if an array is expected.

    }

    /**
     * Can use simply a variable number of arguments, or an array whatever you like.
     * @param obj
     */
    static void varArgsFoo(Object... obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(obj[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Must use an array, varargs (the ... notation) won't work.
     *
     * @param obj
     */
    static void arrayFoo(Object[] obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(obj[i]);
        }
    }
}
```