# Android Async Task Error with ClientService

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I am creating simple system that has a windows service running, complete with a table of users, and I want to validate someone's login credentials by sending something to the service. I am trying to send their username and password, but I keep getting an error with my Async Task. I know that you're not supposed to mess with UI stuff in there and I am not. Originally I had a call to another activity in there but I commented it out. Now the only thing in doInBackground is setting a boolean value to true if the validation was good. From there I read the value after the async has executed, and then put together a bundle to move to the next place. I just don't know what's wrong here. It has been awhile since I've programmed in Android so maybe I'm missing something stupid. If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you. This could also be an issue with sending the information to the service?

UPDATE: After adding in the internet usage in the manifest, if I have the log.d in the program in my doInBackground, it prints out. If I don't have it, the result value stays false. It looks like there is some issue with the connection between my service and android app...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int DATA_FROM_MAIN_ACTIVITY = 1;
    private static final String SERVICEURL = "http://localhost:56638/ClientService.svc";
    private EditText userTextBox, passTextBox;
    private Button loginButton;
    private String uName, pass;
    private Boolean result = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        userTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userTextBox);
        passTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passTextBox);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                uName = userTextBox.getText().toString();
                pass = passTextBox.getText().toString();

                SendLoginMessage task = new SendLoginMessage();
                task.execute(uName, pass);

                if (result.equals(true)) {
                    Intent goToMainScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity.class);
                    goToMainScreen.putExtra("username", uName);
                    goToMainScreen.putExtra("password", pass);

                    startActivityForResult(goToMainScreen,
                            DATA_FROM_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "There was an issue with your username or password.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class SendLoginMessage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Log.d("message almost at server, " + textFromArea, selected,
            // null);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... names) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", names[0]));
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", names[1]));

            String response = null;

            try {
                response = HttpClient.executeHttpPost(SERVICEURL, postParams);

                String newResponse = response.toString();
                newResponse = newResponse.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

                // if user was authenticated...
                if (newResponse.equals(true)) {
                    result = true;
                    // creating an intent to take user to next page.
                    // load their DB objects on the
                    // on create in other activity
                    // pass the username/password to next activity
                    // then make a request to the server for their database
                    // objects.
                    // Intent goToMainScreen = new
                    // Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    // goToMainScreen.putExtra("username", names[0]);
                    // goToMainScreen.putExtra("password", names[1]);

                    // startActivityForResult(goToMainScreen,
                    // DATA_FROM_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ERROR", "exception in background");
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // .show();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error you keep getting?

Comment: This is probably one problem `if (newResponse.equals(true))` it should be if (newResponse.equals("true")) since you are comparing `Strings` now

Comment: I also added the internet use in my manifest but that didn't clear things up. I also changed the .equals to a string check, but that didn't make a difference either.

Comment: I probably have to modify my web service so it knows which method the client intents to use huh?

Comment: Possibly but I would fix the other issues first. Such as the first one I named and you aren't passing the params correctly in `execute()`

Comment: I'm kind of surprised you say that because I debugged the code and they DID come through correctly. How would you pass them? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It has always been my understanding that they should be wrapped in a container or an `ArrayList`. That's why in the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) the method is `execute(Params...params)`

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try as well.

Comment: Ok, I can post as an answer with more clarification and helpful links later when I get time if that is what works for you

Comment: @codeMagic his params are correct. Its called Varargs. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
 private class SendLoginMessage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... names) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", names[0]));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", names[1]));

        String response = null;

        try {
            response = HttpClient.executeHttpPost(SERVICEURL, postParams);

            String newResponse = response.toString();
            newResponse = newResponse.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            // if user was authenticated...
            if (newResponse.equals("true")) {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "exception in background");
        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result) {
                Intent goToMainScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                goToMainScreen.putExtra("username", uName);
                goToMainScreen.putExtra("password", pass);

                startActivityForResult(goToMainScreen,
                        DATA_FROM_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "There was an issue with your username or password.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }

}
```

and in your `onClick()` just call `execute()`

```
 uName = userTextBox.getText().toString();
 pass = passTextBox.getText().toString();

 SendLoginMessage task = new SendLoginMessage();
 task.execute(uName, pass);
```

After execution is finished `onPostExecute()` will be called and your `Activity` will start depending on result variable.

Don't check your result variable after you invoke `execute()` because `execute()` is invoked asynchronously. By the time you check your global result variable, your `doInBackground()` might not have been finished. Using my approach you don't need a global variable. Please read doc carefully before using any component.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for commenting on this. I learned a lot by your way of doing things. The flow is a lot smoother and it makes more sense. Thank you for covering things so nice and informative.