# onPostExecute does not execute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

After completing the task ImageUploadTask(), the method itself will return sResponse which supposedly would trigger the onPostExecute(). However, I am unable to get onPostExecute() to work.

The code for the Intent is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (bitmap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (subject.getText() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter subject title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (msg == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {                
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading",
                        "Please wait...", true);
                new ImageUploadTask().execute();
            }
        }
    });
```

The ImageUploadTask() is:

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://203.117.178.181/test3/postdata2.php");

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        entity.addPart("userfile", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                "myImage.jpg"));
        entity.addPart("subject", new StringBody(subject.getText()
                .toString()));
        entity.addPart("message", new StringBody(msg.getText()
                .toString()));
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                localContext);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

        String sResponse = reader.readLine();
        return sResponse;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.exception_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
    // (null);
}
```

The code for the onPostExecute() is:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
    super.onPostExecute(sResponse);
    try {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();

        if (sResponse != null) {
            JSONObject JResponse = new JSONObject(sResponse);
            int success = JResponse.getInt("SUCCESS");
            String message = JResponse.getString("MESSAGE");
            if (success == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Photo uploaded successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                subject.setText("");
                msg.setText("");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.exception_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
}}
```

Thanks in advance =D

Comment: getting any error plz paste logcat here

Comment: Benflop pls post the stack trace. you are probably getting an exception

Comment: @Raghunandan but I am not receiving any exception...ImageUploadTask() was completed without exception but it still did not execute onPostExecute..i followed your advise..I typed in the following code:

    catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

Comment: @Benflop if `doInbackground` is executed after its execution onPostExecute is invoked according to the docs. Quoting from docs `onPostExecute(Result)`, **invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes**. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter. SO you might me getting exception

Comment: @Raghunandan my onPostExecute method is below doInBackground but both are in the same ImageUploadTask class but not in the UI thread...does this mean doInBackground is executed before onPostExecute is invoked?

Comment: @Benflop did you even read the docs. For more info check the docs under the topic The 4 steps.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @Raghunandan i just read the docs. erm doInBackground is executed first and once doInBackground is completed it return sResponse, which is passed as a parameter in onPostExecute. i do not have any code running on onProgressUpdate and onPreExecute though...

Comment: @Benflop then `doInbackgound` is not executed. may be you get exception

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String... sResponse) {
```

Add the `...`

**Edit:**  also as `@Raghunandan` points out, you cannot call `Toast` from your `doInBackground`, it's a mere background thread and does not support UI commands. For that, you must use `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()`.

Comment: why this `(String... sResponse)` ? when op has `String sResponse = reader.readLine();
        return sResponse`

Comment: I'm not sure the role "..." plays. Usually for me, that's what fixes it :) I'm looking for an explanation. If I find it, I will add it to my answer :)

Comment: this is not the answer to the question posted. its varargs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {

        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
     try {
        if (sResponse != null) {
            JSONObject JResponse = new JSONObject(sResponse);
            int success = JResponse.getInt("SUCCESS");
            String message = JResponse.getString("MESSAGE");
            if (success == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Photo uploaded successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                subject.setText("");
                msg.setText("");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.exception_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your might be getting exception.

You have this  in `doInbackground`.

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            getString(R.string.exception_message),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`doInbackground` is invoked on a background thread. You cannot display toast/ update ui from `doInbackground`. So return response and display toast in `onPostExecute`

You need to change this

```
     catch (Exception e) {
    if (dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            getString(R.string.exception_message),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    return null;
}
```

To

```
     catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStacktrace();
      }
```

For more info check the docs under the topic **The 4 steps**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: That's true. To display Toast, use `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

Probably your doInBackGround method is throwing an exception. Also you can remove super.
super.onPostExecute() as it is redundant.