# Obscure Scala: what does following mean in scala? ( : _* )

Tags: scala, syntax

Hi I have following code

```
CookieMock(response, email).cookies: _*
```

.cookies is type `def cookies: scala.Seq[Cookie]`.
What does `:_*` mean in Scala?

Thanks

Comment: I believe `(:_*)` is the monkey face emoticon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with Java

here is the same explanation in Java:

[varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java)

Because * is not a type, you add the underscore.

```
def printInts(ints: Int*) = ints.mkString(",") 
printInts(1,2,3)
//printInts(List(1,2,3)) //type mismatch; found : List[Int] required: Int
printInts(List(1,2,3): _*)
```

paste this to codebrew.io this will clarify.

Comment: How do you execute the code inside that site?

Comment: I don't know how this makes sense to the OP. "Because * is not a type, you add the underscore." is called "folk etymology" in the dictionary. BTW, `*` can name a type.

Comment: cdshines - How to execute the code inside that site?                                     use codebrew.io

Answer (score 0):

The `:` is type ascription. `_*` is the type you ascribe when you need a `Seq[A]` to be treated as `A*`.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html

> The following are examples of ascription:
>
> ```
> Nil: List[String]
> Set(values: _*)
> "Daniel": AnyRef
> ```
>
> Ascription is basically just an up-cast performed at compile-time for the sake of the type checker. Its use is not common, but it does happen on occasion. The most often seen case of ascription is invoking a varargs method with a single Seq parameter. This is done by ascribing the _* type (as in the second example above).

Comment: What is Type Ascription? Could you give an example with actual values. Let's say we have Seq(1, 2, 3, 4) what would be the result of using :_*? Why would you use it?