# How to add a 2nd argument to doInBackground for android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this asynctask working fine for what I want with a single argument (remove the param2 and it runs) but as soon as I attempt to add the 2nd argument I receive:

> Syntax error on token "param2", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

which to be honest, I've never come across.

The function is below (havent included the parameters as I know they've worked in other functions and do work when used individually, but as a pair....) I believe I may be trying to add them incorrectly?

Do I need to make them into an array and use the array as a parameter? If so, how would I go about it? (Still getting the hang of android!)

**My function**

```
private class LoadList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<List>> {
    private Exception exception = null;
    /**
     * Main worker method
     */
    protected ArrayList<List> doInBackground(String... param1, param2) { 
        try {
            //Call web service
            return Utils.getWebService(getApplicationContext()).getListInfo(param1[0], param2[1]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If any more is needed let me know, please, and thank you!

Comment: This is not an android-specific problem: 1) you need to understand *java varargs* and if they are the right thing to use here... 2) do you know what *AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<List>>* means?

Comment: it looks like you come from another world : PHP !! `param2` needs to be typed. [Read this link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java)

Comment: I understand the basic theory behind AsyncTask and its construction, just passing multiple String parameters confused me @DaniEll ...

Comment: Also, on a sidenote.... being voted down would be helpful if a comment was left explaining why, so I don't make whatever mistake I made again....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private class LoadList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<List>> {
private Exception exception = null;
/**
 * Main worker method
 */
protected ArrayList<List> doInBackground(String... param) { 
    try {
        //Call web service
        return Utils.getWebService(getApplicationContext()).getListInfo(param[0], param[1]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exception = e;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Try this

Comment: How on earth I missed this solution I'll never understand. Thank you so much @Mahesh!

Comment: (I can accept the answer in 9 minutes, which I shall!)

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to pass a variable to the `AsyncTask.doInBackground` method:

- using it's varargs parameter : `String... param`. You can add many value to `param` when calling the execute method:

  `LoadList loadistTask = new LoadList();
  loadistTask.execute(new String[]{"my value","another value"});` After you will access them like this: `param[0]` , `param[1]`, etc.
- The other method is to create a custom constructor and pass your variable to it:

  `LoadList loadistTask = new LoadList("my var here");
  loadistTask.execute();`

  ```
  private class LoadList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<List>> {
  private Exception exception = null;
  private String myVar;
  /**
  * constructor
  */
  public LoadList(String myVar) {
      this.myVar = myVar;
  }

  /**
   * Main worker method
   */
  protected ArrayList<List> doInBackground(String... param) {
      // this.myVar to access your var in the doInBackground method.
      try {
          //Call web service
          return Utils.getWebService(getApplicationContext()).getListInfo(param[0], param[1]);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          exception = e;
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to pass an array of String.

Snippet:

AsyncTask:

```
private class LoadList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<List>> {
    private Exception exception = null;
    /**
     * Main worker method
     */
    protected ArrayList<List> doInBackground(String... params) { 
        try {
            //Call web service
            return Utils.getWebService(getApplicationContext()).getListInfo(param1[0], param2[1]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Call it as:

```
LoadList loadistTask = new LoadList();
loadistTask.execute(new String[]{"value 1","value 2"});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats how I thought it would need to be done! A previous answer worked for me also, but thank you for giving me that!

Answer (score 0):

Just call your AsyncTask with several arguments, like this:

```
new LoadList().execute("value 1", "value 2")
```

The thing is that the argument `String... param` can handle any number of arguments and bundles them in an array. See Mahesh's answer on how to use them. If you add another argument after having `String... param` the compiler won't know when to assign a variable of a call to that argument.

So what you can do technically in Java is `foo(String a, String b, String... c)` but you can't do `foo(String a, String... b, String c)`.

However, in your case, since `doInBackground(String... param)` is a predefined method signature you won't be able to add more arguments, because the framework wouldn't be able to call it.