# Method parameters in java

Tags: java, methods, parameters

The only thing i know is that (...) indicates that Texture key is an optional parameter for the method.Are there any other uses ?

```
Texture[] key;                              //1
public Animation( Texture ... key ) {       //2
    this.key = key;                         //3
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use varargs in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

`Texture ... key` does not denote optional parameters, but actually an unspecified number of arguments to a method. Java treats the variable-length argument list as an array.

More information on [VarArgs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Comment: Oh now i see, i didnt know that ... was called varArgs. Thanks a lot for the documentation link.

Answer (score 2):

```
Texture ... key
```

This is used if you don't know how many parameters will be passed.  key will be an array with the parameters that were passed to the Animation method.  You can pass n number of parameters of type Texture.

Answer (score 2):

`...` indicates a *varargs* parameters. It's basically an array that can be empty.

So

```
Animation();
```

is a valid call, as well as

```
Animation(key1, key2);
```

Note that only one *varargs* parameter is allowed per method and that it must be the last parameter of the method