# Triple Dot (...) Syntax in Java? Meaning and conversions?

Tags: java, syntax

I have this AVL tree with a balance method:

```
private void setBalance(Node... nodes) {
    for (Node n : nodes)
        n.height = height(n.right) - height(n.left);
}
```

It uses a (...) syntax I have not encountered before. I can't find it on google or SO. It seems to be some type of list syntax, or array. Looks like something I would find in ruby.

Could someone knowledgeable in Java's syntax explain this code to me, and perhaps show me a version without the ... syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: You can treat `Node...` as `Node []`, or just change the `Node...` to `Node []` and `setBalance` will still work. Take a look at the [Arbitrary Number of Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) . Basically same are arrays but can be zero to many.
More [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java) that might also assist.

Comment: Actually it can zero to many (at least in Java 8), so you could call `setBalance()` ;) . To do one to many, you might use `private void setBalance(Node one, Node... many)` or something equivilent :P

Comment: You are right just tested in Java 7 Zero to many :)

Comment: Still a good answer ;)