# Function in Java similar to printf from C

Tags: java

I want to create my own custom function in Java which work exactly same  like the `printf` in C.

Like

```
printf("My name is %c, my age is %d", "B", 23);
```

Which will print `My name is B, my age is 23`

or

```
 printf("No of items %d", 2);
```

which will print `No of items 2`.

Comment: search in the javadocs for: `String.format()` also check this: `System.out.format()`

Comment: You can also create a custom made method for that...

Comment: You can use `System.out.printf`

Comment: `System.out.printf`?

Comment: see format method doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: yea I want to know how to create a customized method

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use varargs in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java)

Comment: you need to add your own full stop ".". Java won't add that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create function like 
function(String line,Object ...args)

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple such methods in Java.

#### [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

> Returns a formatted string using the specified format string and arguments.

and

#### [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) can use [`PrintStream.printf(String, Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

and

#### The [`Formatter` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) applies to both of the above

For example,

```
String fmt = "i = %d%n";
int iv = 101;
System.out.print(String.format(fmt, iv));
System.out.printf(fmt, iv);
Formatter out = new Formatter(System.out);
out.format(fmt, iv);
out.flush();
```

Outputs

```
i = 101
i = 101
i = 101
```

### tl;dr from your Question

Use "%s" for a `String` and `System.out.printf` like

```
System.out.printf("My name is %s,my age is %d%n", "B", 23);
System.out.printf("No of items %d%n", 2);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
My name is B,my age is 23
No of items 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for System.out.printf(). it acts same like as printf function in c.

Answer (score 0):

you can code this way.. please share the feedback, as I tried some happy cases only.

```
public class Test1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    printf("My name is %s ,my age is %d","B",23);
 }

 public static void printf(final String in, final Object... args) {
    System.out.println(String.format(in, args));
 }
}
```

Output  :  `My name is B ,my age is 23`

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
System.out.print("My name is "+"B"+",my age is " +23);
```

or

```
System.out.print("No of items "+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String name = "B";
    int age = 23;
    System.out.printf("My name is %s, My age is %d", name,age);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("No of items %d", 2);
```

Output:

```
My name is B, My age is 23
No of items 2
```