# error: no suitable method found for println(String,double) System.out.println

Tags: java

```
java:19: error: no suitable method found for println(String,double)
   System.out.println("The health is %.2f",kiloliters);
             ^
    method PrintStream.println() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(char) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(long) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(float) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(double) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(char[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PrintStream.println(Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
2 errors
```

```java
if(kiloliters > 1000 && kiloliters < 10000){ //test if the inputted number is in between 1000 and 10000
   kiloliters = (kiloliters + 150)/140;
   System.out.println("The health is %.2f",kiloliters);
```

Comment: If you want to print by providing `format` containing placeholders and `values` for them as other parameters use `System.out.format` or `System.out.printf`.

Comment: `System.out.printf("The health is %.2f%n", kiloliters);` Mind the `%n` newline.

Comment: Possibly related: [JAVA function like printf of C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31645322)

Answer (score 2):

Java [println()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) is the original  "print text" method.  You can use it like this:

`System.out.println("The health is " + kiloliters);`

[printf()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf) is a newer addition to Java; it allows "formatted printing" like C, C++ and C# (among many others).   You can use it like this:

`System.out.printf("The health is %.2f",kiloliters);`

Yet another option is [String.format()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format):

`System.out.println(String.format("The health is %.2f",kiloliters));`

Comment: ... or since Java 15 non-static [`String#formatted​(Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) for instance `System.out.println("The health is %.2f".formatted(kiloliters));`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.out.format()` instead:

```java
System.out.format("The health is %.2f\n",kiloliters);
```