# Why is there ... in a java function?

Tags: java, swing

I'm following a java tutorial named "Java Swing first programs" and I noticed something that troubles me. At one point, there's a function written like this:

```
private void createLayout(JComponent... arg)
```

I was wandering why there was a `...` and what those it do?

The tutorial: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/

Comment: check varargs in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation for [Java varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java