# How to call a vararg method of arrays?

Tags: java, jooq

I discovered a strange method in JOOQ api.

```
Batch batch(Query query, Object[]... bindings);
```

I am curious how to call it without specifying arguments manually.

```
public int g(Object[]... args) {
    return args.length;
}
```

Fails:

```
assertEquals(2, g(new Object[] { new Object[0], new Object[0] }));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use varargs in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

#### What does the API mean?

The intent of the API is to provide a set of bind values for a batch statement in a matrix form where each outer array element corresponds to an individual statement in the batch, and each inner array element corresponds to a bind value.

#### How is it called?

There are several ways. Let's assume this query here:

```
Query query = DSL.query("INSERT INTO t(a, b) VALUES (?, ?)", null, null);
```

E.g. using classic matrix creation in Java (the varargs isn't helpful here):

```
batch(query, new Object[][] {
    { 1, "a" }, // Record 1 to insert
    { 2, "b" }, // Record 2 to insert
    { 3, "c" }  // Record 3 to insert
});
```

Or, by using individual arrays (this is where varargs may help):

```
batch(query, 
    new Object[] { 1, "a" }, // Record 1 to insert
    new Object[] { 2, "b" }, // Record 2 to insert
    new Object[] { 3, "c" }  // Record 3 to insert
);
```

The latter is particularly useful if you have some pre-existing jOOQ record structure, and you want to pass them as bind variables to a batch, e.g. by using [`Record.intoArray()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#intoArray--):

```
batch(query,
    record1.intoArray(),
    record2.intoArray(),
    record3.intoArray()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test fails because Java implicitly creates an array for the three dot notation. In your case the method g gets an array with one element and the first element of this array is again an array (your array with two instances of `Object`).

Hence you can omit the additional array:

```
assertEquals(2, g(new Object[0], new Object[0]));
```

So you can use the `batch()` method by just passing the vararg arguments with an explicit array:

```
batch(query, new Object(), new Object())
```

Comment: If the question is correct, you need `Object[]`s as arguments to `batch`, not `Object`s.