# How to pass array parameter with inline declare?

Tags: java

I have a method as

```
private void show(Object[] arr) {
  for (Object o : arr) {
    System.out.println(o);
  }
}
```

I would like to call this method as

```
// belows are not valid but I'd like to achieve 
show({1,2,3});
show(new String["a","b","c"])
```

but I don't want to create an array to call this method. *(Please don't be suggest to change the signature of my **show** method.This is just an example.Actual method that I use is from 3rd party lib.)*

How can I achieve this by utility classes or anything else?

Comment: use varargs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java

Comment: @rahulroc I can't change my **show** method parameter.

Comment: `show(Object... arr)`? Then you can say `show(1, 2, 3)` or `show("a", "b", "c")` ... etc

Comment: @Cataclysm If you can't change the `show` method then you're stuck having to declare a variable, `show(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3})`

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry .. I can't change my method signature because my actual method that I use is from third pary lib.

Comment: You can't create an array without creating an array.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks `show(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3})` this is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is not a way to pass an array to a method without declare it, you are looking for a "single line data instatiation for array"... or by the real name "in-line declare"

```
show(new Object[]{"a","b","c"});
```

Comment: OK ... I got it `in-line declare`. I don't know how to call this :)

Answer (score 4):

You can either use varargs as mentioned in the comments or declare the array this way:

```
show(new String[] {"a","b","c"})
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) wrapper method:

```
private void myShow(Object... arr){
    show(arr);
}

// No change to your existing 3rd party method:
private void show(Object[] arr) {
  for (Object o : arr) {
    System.out.println(o);
  }
}
```

You can then call the wrapper method like this:

```
myShow("a","b","c");
myShow(1,2,3,4);
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: By OP :  (Please don't be suggest to change the signature of my show method.This is just an example.)

Comment: This does not change the signature.   A vararg is an array still.

Comment: @Cataclysm, That doesn't change the signature. The args still remain an array type.

Comment: I can't change my method signature because my actual method that I use is from third pary lib

Comment: It does change the signature, without modify the method, you can't use varargs against it, so the OP could use `show(1, 2, 3, 4)` with their current implementation :P

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using varargs. A simple edit to your function will not only allow an array of objects but allow you to accomplish what you are looking for.

Instead of using `Object[]` use `Object...`