# What is the meaning X ... x in android AsynTask's parameter in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Please tell my what ... means in "doInBackground(X...x)"

I have read the excellent answer by Kartik Domadiya on

> What arguments are passed into AsyncTask?

and It helps my a lot. However, I still cannot understand the 3 dots in the following. I need some concrete examples.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<X, Y, Z>

protected void onPreExecute(){

}
 protected Z doInBackground(X...x){

}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Y y){
}

protected void onPostExecute(Z z){
}
```

If I have to pass more than 1 parameters to doInBackground(), will I just replace X by the type of the first parameter?

For instance, if I will pass three parameters to doInBackground(), with types of int, String, String, respectively , and make a result with a type of String. During the progress update, I will use a String type parameter, will I implement the class like that?

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<int, String, String> {
    protect void onPreExecute() {
    }
    protect String doInBackground(int ... x) {
    }
    protect void onProgressUpdate(String y) {
    }
    protect void onPostExecute(String z) {
    }
```

Comment: Related canonical question: [When do you use varags in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java)?

Answer (score 0):

According to docs:

> An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An asynchronous task is defined by **3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result**.
>   These three types can be explained as:

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

1.**Params**- the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.

2.**Progress**- the type of the progress units published during the background computation.

3.**Result**, the type of the result of the background computation.

You can get further details [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Now; **X is generally an URL that is sent to the task upon execution.**

Now; The `...` (dots) implies the array of variable arguments i.e. **A variable number of arguments of the same type can be passed to a method and treated as an array.**

For instance;

the three dot stays for `vargars`. you can access it like a String[].

If a method takes as parameter a varargs, you can call it with multiple values for the vargars type:

```
public void myMethod(String... values) {}
you can call like myMethod("a", "b");
```

in myMethod `values[0]` is equals "a" and `values[1]` is equals to "b". If you have a method with multiple args, the vargars argument has to be the last: for instance:

```
 public void myMethod(int first, double second, String... values) {}
```

Comment: I just do not under stand the 3 dots in doInBackground(X...x), can you tell me what ... means?

Comment: I think it should clarify your doubts

Comment: Thank you very muck . By the way, if I have to pass an integer array of parameters, will I replace X by Integer or just int?

Comment: Of Course; you can just use something like `Integer ...x`

Comment: I now understand it quit well, with your help. I am just pity that I just have 6 reputations now and cannot increase your reputations. Thank you again.

Comment: If it was helpful, you can click on the accept answer sign(The green tick mark) to help me and don't feel pity because everyone was once a beginner

Answer (score 0):

It means you can pass an undeterminate number of parameters of that type.
It is a shorthand for `X [] x`. Which means the parameter is actually an array of X.

Example:

```
public void doSomething(String ... stings){
  String [] str = strings;
  <process the stings>
}
```

somewhere else:

```
doSomething("One","of","many","stirngs");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that means I can pass an array of data with same type, right? But how can I pass parameters with different types. Will I had to wrap these parameter into an object?

Comment: But you pass it as a coma separated list of parameters.

Comment: When you write the function you read the parameters as an array of that type.

Comment: I now understand it quit well, with your help. I am just pity that I just have 6 reputations now and cannot increase your reputations. Thank you again.

Comment: If this helped you, you should be able to accept the answer with the green tick :).

Comment: I am sorry, I just get in and I have only 6 reputations. The system only allow  those to click the green tick, with reputations more than 15. :(

Answer (score 0):

It means that the argumetns could be zero or more Int objects (or an array of them) for that method.

You can have more details here:

"Arbitrary Number of Arguments" section  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs

So you could do

```
new MyTask().execute();
new MyTask().execute(1);
new MyTask().execute(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: I was programming in JavaScript and ruby,  and was not familiar with Java. I will read varargs for more detail, thank you.