# What is the "..." operator used while receiving arrays in java method arguments

Tags: java

```
public class Venus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] x = {1,2,3};
        int y[] = {4,5,6};
        new Venus().go(x,y);
    }
    void go(int[]... z) { 
        /*
         *here where my doubt goes about how the "..." operator works
         */

    for(int[] a : z)
        System.out.print(a[0]);
}
```

}

output of this code snippet is "14"

Comment: Read about varags in Java

Comment: [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java

Comment: Please consider reading a Java tutorial or textbook.  For example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...` is the [elipsis (varargs) operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs). In short, it's a syntactic sugar that allows you to pass a variable number of arguments to the method using commas (`,`). Inside the method, the argument is treated as an array.

So `int[]... z` means that `z` is treated as an array of `int[]`, or `int[][]`.

Comment: If you think that this answer was helpful you might want to consider upvoting this answer to say "thank you" another way here at Stack Overlflow :-)